# selenium: bypass access denied

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to navigate a website with Selenium, but I'm getting an error: Access Denied. You do not have permission to access "http://tokopedia.com/" on this server.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys




CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r'C:/chromedriver.exe'
tokopedia = "https://tokopedia.com/"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
driver.get(tokopedia)

print(driver.page_source)
```

how to solve it? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. It is working for me -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

tokopedia = "https://tokopedia.com/"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(tokopedia)

print(driver.page_source)
```